# SQL Server Management Studio 19.1 does not load

Tags: ssms

Somehow SSMS complains about a section `system.net/defaultProxy`:

Log in Path: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\15.0\ActivityLog.xml`:

```
<entry>
  <record>95</record>
  <time>2023/11/06 10:14:30.368</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>CreateInstance failed for package [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=16.200.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---&gt; System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---&gt; System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.net/defaultProxy. (C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\19.0_IsoShell\Ssms.exe.config line 1232)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio..ctor()&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---&gt; System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.net/defaultProxy. (C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\19.0_IsoShell\Ssms.exe.config line 1232)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio..ctor()System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.net/defaultProxy. (C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\19.0_IsoShell\Ssms.exe.config line 1232)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)</description>
  <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
  <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
  <errorinfo></errorinfo>
</entry>
```

The error message complains about this section in `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\19.0_IsoShell\Ssms.exe.config`:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

If i remove the line:

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
```

SSMS opens. But after opening SSMS again the file gets overridden again and the error shows again.

I have uninstalled, repaired a few times with no help.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: The error is saying that the config file is invalid at the specified path. You could try removing that file (or renaming it) and then start the application and seeing what error you get.

Comment: @ThomA added more details to the question. Problem seems to be this line: `<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"/>`